# a script that allows you to change the default account for MS Teams

Tags: c#, credentials, microsoft-teams

I want to create a script that will change the currently-logged-in user of the Microsoft Teams client. The aim is to have the following workflow:

1. Quit Teams Client
2. Run the Script
3. Open Team Client, at which point the logged-in user should be the one determined by the script, rather than whoever was logged in in step 1.

Teams stores the user's password information in Windows Credentials. If you delete or edit these Credentials, Teams will not automatic login when you open Teams client.

Is there any way to do this? Please help, thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming

Comment: Hi, could you explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: I understand that one way I might be able to adopt is：
Replace the default account of the Teams client with the target account, then clear the previous Windows Credentials, and generate the Credentials of the target account, and then add them to Windows Credentials.
There are still two problems in the solution. One is that the place where saved the default account of the Teams client has not been found. Another problem is that Windows Credentials is fragmented, and the way Teams generate Windows Credentials is unclear and no related documentation has been found.

Comment: @ThomasTang - I understand you want to change the user through script but please help me understand what is your end goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium to automate your steps. just search on the internet you will find a way

Comment: But selenium  is just using for Web, I was using for Teams Client.